# Multiple Context path for different war in WildFly

Tags: spring, web, jboss, wildfly, contextroot

I am deploying my web app in WildFly 23.0.0 Final and I'm using spring application.

I would like to have different Context path for the diffrent war in one deploy:

http://ip:8080/xxx-ui

http://ip:8080/xxx-rest

http://ip:8080/xxx-cron

Can someone show me how to do this ?

Comment: Are you deploying an EAR with multiple WAR's?

Comment: yes, it will be 3 WAR´S

Comment: All WAR's have to have a unique context path. Are you deploying them in an EAR or each individually? If it's an EAR you can define the context path in the application.xml file. If each is deployed separately there are a few ways it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly has Undertow's [filter/rewrite](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/configuration/filter/rewrite/index.html).

First, you add an "xxx" filter for the URLs you want. For example, filter request with `/xxx-*`. The jboss.cli command is as follows:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=xxx:add(predicate="regex('/xxx-(.*)')")
```

Then, you add the rewrite/filter. In this example, the request could go to "/xxx" (the EAR's context path) plus the WAR's context path.

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/rewrite=xxx:add(target="/xxx/$${1}")
```

As a side note, it looks like a job for a load balancer, or some other network-related application, like [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/traffic-routing/rewrites/rewrite-requests/#set-the-uri), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [AWS Cloud Front](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html)